# Best way to create product with “specifications” field?

Tags: drupal-7

I am using Ubercart for products on a Drupal site. I want to extend this product to show a wide range if different information on products. One of the bits of info I want to show, is "specifications".

Take [this product](http://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-za/all-products/food-processors/multipro-compact/fp210-food-processor-0wfp210002?TabSegment=specifications#specifications) as an example. It has various categories of specs, e.g:

- Attachment and Capacities
- General Specifications
- Function and Size

But each of those categories, has actual values underneath them. E.g. Under "attachment and capacities" you have:

- Citrus press:Yes
- Dough tool:Yes
- Mini bowl :Yes
- Etc

When I create a new product, I want to be able to add infinite amounts of specifications, that fall under a group.

The best way I have found to do this is using Inline Entities. But this is very slow. Is there no better "field type" I could use to demonstrate this relationship? I.e. one where I can infinitely add categories of values to a specific node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Product Specification](https://www.drupal.org/project/product_specification) module to achieve the same.

> This module allows you to attach product specification data to any
>   entity in Drupal 7. Mostly we can use this module to store product
>   specifications on product display page.